# Explanation of network-scripts ifcfg directives and DEVICE mapping

Tags: networking, networkmanager

in RHEL/CentOS 7.9 the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` **ifcfg-** files,

where can I find a document explaining all the directives that

- can be in the file?
- what directives go with a given `TYPE=` directive,

  - `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.49.53/sysconfig.txt` mentions: *The items that can be defined in an ifcfg file depend on the  interface type.  The really obvious ones I'm not going to bother to define; you can figure out what "IPADDR" is, I think...*
  - I am interested in `TYPE=Ethernet` and `TYPE=InfiniBand` specifically,
- **for the directive `DEVICE=`** where under `/etc` or under `/dev` does it happen that it specifically uses the syntax `em1` for my network name, versus *eno1* or *enp0s20f0u12* or whatever else?  This is from the *biosdevname* and *predictable network interface names* shi..stuff I believe.

**Can someone tell me where the** *items that can be defined in an ifcfg* **is documented** ?

Comment: Did you see `man 5 nm-settings-ifcfg-rh`?

Comment: @ Edward - not until now.  That's a start, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apropos tells me information on `ifcfg` can be found in the following man pages:

```bash
» apropos ifcfg
ifcfg (8)            - simplistic script which replaces ifconfig IP management
nm-settings-ifcfg-rh (5) - Description of ifcfg-rh settings plugin
```

I think that `nm-settings-ifcfg-rh` contains most items you are interested in:

```bash
» man 5 nm-settings-ifcfg-rh
```